# Twitter Bootstrap: border-radius: 0 \0/;

Tags: twitter, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the newest release of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) (2.0) I came across this line:

```
border-radius: 0 \0/;
```

What does the \0/ do? Is the some obscure css trick or simply a typo?

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css#L568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the `\0/` is a construct that IE 9 ignores, but other browsers don't, so this line's there to set `border-radius` to 0 for IE 9 only.

The Twitter Bootstrap developers left a comment in their [sass source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/forms.less) (although, the accompanying [commit message](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/b77161f8647f791319c684a191c2308b6dd05100) isn't exactly self-assured):

```
border-radius: 0 e("\0/"); // Nuke border-radius for IE9 only
```

[Paul Irish's fairly exhaustive list of CSS browser hacks](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/) says that `\0/` after an attribute is a hack that targets IE 8 and 9.